# How can I check if my seed matches a BTC address?

Tags: wallet-recovery, lost-transactions

I have a seed with 12 words from Coinbase Wallet. The derivation path is: `Segwit Native (p2wpkh) m/84'/0'/0' BIP84`.

The first address generated seems to be wrong because it does not get generated anymore.

I can't get access to the funds with Electrum and a gap limit of 10000.

I'm sure that the address contains my funds and no other transactions than my initial are visible in the blockchain explorer.

How do I do get access to that address?

Can this be somehow brueteforced or something?

Answer (score 3):

In HD wallets it rarely happen that a gap of more than 20 is being used. It relates to bip32 standard in most cases. And it may happen in only few cases:

-if the receiver is a payment processor that puts out hundreds of invoices and only few are being paid.

It doesn't sound like your case though. I would suggest using [IanColeman](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/) website, please remember to use it in offline mode and be very careful about it anyway. I wouldn't use it with a bigger amount of funds personally.